# Programmatically set property expressions on custom SSIS component

Tags: c#, ssis

I have created a custom component for my SSIS package, and would like for it to try to auto-link some variables. Currently I am manually linking them via the UI Properties->Misc->Expressions->(Selecting the property name, and expression to link to it), as shown below:

[image]

I currently am struggling with the following code:

```
public override void InitializeTask(Connections connections, VariableDispenser variableDispenser, IDTSInfoEvents events, IDTSLogging log, EventInfos eventInfos, LogEntryInfos logEntryInfos, ObjectReferenceTracker refTracker)
{
    base.InitializeTask(connections, variableDispenser, events, log, eventInfos, logEntryInfos, refTracker);

    using (Package pkg = ... /*not sure how to get 'this' package*/)
    {
        // Iterate through executables to try to find this TaskHost.
        foreach (Executable pExec in pkg.Executables)
        {
            TaskHost aTaskHost = (TaskHost)pExec;
            if (aTaskHost.InnerObject.GetType() == this.GetType())
            {
                // Iterate over variables, to try to match some task's properties.
                foreach (Variable myVar in pkg.Variables)
                {
                    if (aTaskHost.Properties.Contains("PackageName") &&
                        Regex.IsMatch(myVar.QualifiedName, "PackageName", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    {
                        aTaskHost.SetExpression("PackageName", myVar.Expression);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to go all the way down to set the expression level; some of my other variables may change so, instead of linking a .Value, I want to go to the .Expression.

However, I am not sure how to get the current package or, even if I get it, that everything will link up properly. So, I am wondering if anyone has programmatically linked a system variable to a custom component's property expression at the initialization of it.

Comment: do you want to use system variable or user defined variable?

Comment: Both, if possible. Some of the system variables being.. the package name and start time. Other user variables are things as data pulled from a file at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way, that I saw, to accomplish this via the UI Properties. However, if connected via a SSIS UI then it can work. The snippets below is the method I took. Hopefully it can help someone else looking to mess with the custom component stuff more.

So if you have the following SSIS UI class:

```
class PackageStatusSSISUI : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Design.IDtsTaskUI
{
    private TaskHost _taskHost;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl GetView()
    {
        PackageStatusForm editor = new PackageStatusForm(this._taskHost, this._serviceProvider);
        return editor;
    }

    public void Initialize(TaskHost taskHost, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this._taskHost = taskHost;
        this._serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
}
```

Then if the windows form to connect to it, you can access the task host variables and set expressions:

```
public partial class PackageStatusForm : Form
{
    public PackageStatusForm(TaskHost taskHost, IServiceProvider serviceprovider)
    {
        this.TaskHost = taskHost;
        this.ServiceProvider = serviceprovider;

        InitializeComponent();

        if (this.TaskHost != null && this.TaskHost.Variables != null)
        {
            // Goes though each variable, to display the shortcut
            foreach (Variable var in taskHost.Variables)
            {
                variableList.Items.Add(var.QualifiedName);
            }

            // Can set labels to variable name, text boxes to allow the expressions, etc
            foreach (LabelTextDisplay ppt in this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                this.TaskHost.SetExpression(ppt.PropertyName, ppt.ExpressionValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- "There is no way", is incorrect. Instead of trying to change the value, change the Expression of the variable (and leave the .EvaluateAsExpression = true. pkg.Variables["SrcConString"].Expression = "MyDbConnectionString"; This is very important, because it seems like if EvaluateAsExpression=false, then the Expression to change the ConnectionString of a Connection doesn't work, and the connection fails. (But you can change the Variable value.) But if put .EvaluateExpression = true, and you Modify the the variable.Expression then it works and the database connection is changed and the package will work!  Its possible I didn't fully understand the problem. But for me the trick was to find a way to be able to change the expression. Now I have a solution to that!